# What is use of serviceWorker.js file in create-react-app , and why serviceWorker.unregister(); in index.js?

Tags: reactjs

I am newbie in react , I want to know what the use of `serviceWorker.js` file in **create-react-app** , and why `serviceWorker.unregister();` this is written in `index.js` file ?

any react expert please explain in detail :)

Comment: Service worker is not react specific.

Comment: then why it is used in create-react-app ?

Comment: I mean it is not "just" react specific. It can be used without react also. You can read about service workers here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: That file is there to implement service worker in that react app.

Comment: Service worker is a browser feature, not a react feature.